# The keyboard doesnt move up when I want to write in the text field. How should I fix it? sweift 3 IOS8

Tags: swift3, keyboard, xcode8, textfield, move

I am new to Xcode and I am trying to make an app and would like to move the keyboard when I write in the text field, but the view doesn't move and I have no idea how to fix it. Why and how can I fix it?  swift 3 IOS8
Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class LoginController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var loginTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var topInfoLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var uiHolderView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var logo: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var forgotPasswordButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var uiHolderViewCenterConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var loginBox: UIView!

fileprivate var isResettingPassword = false
fileprivate var keyboardIsShown = false
fileprivate var topUIHolderInitialValue : CGFloat?
fileprivate var uiHolderCenterInitialValue : CGFloat?    

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loginTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false        
    loadUI()

    DataManager.isCourseViewPresentedOnce = false
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let _token = DataManager.token?.token
    if _token?.isEmpty == false {
        print("will use old token")

        if TokenManager.hasTokenExpired(){
            CommunicationManager.renewToken({json -> Void in
                TokenManager.saveRenewedToken(json)
                self.navigateToUniversityController()
            }, onFailure: {error -> Void in})
        }else{
            navigateToUniversityController()
        }

    }else{
        print("no token")
    }

    registerForKeyboardNotifications()
    emailTextField.delegate = self
    passwordTextField.delegate = self
    emailTextField.text = String()
    passwordTextField.text = String()
    uiHolderCenterInitialValue = uiHolderViewCenterConstraint.constant      
}

fileprivate func navigateToUniversityController(){

    DispatchQueue.main.async{

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToUniversityController", sender: self)
    }        
}

@IBAction func loginButtonClick(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if isResettingPassword == false {
        login()
    }else{
        resetPassword()
    }        
}

@IBAction func forgotPasswordClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if isResettingPassword == false{
        showForgotPasswordAlert()
        isResettingPassword = true
        forgotPasswordButton.setTitle("Cancel", for: UIControlState())
        passwordTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        passwordTextField.isHidden = true
        loginButton.setTitle("Send email", for: UIControlState())
        emailTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    } else {
        print("cancel clicked")
        resetUIToInitialState()
    }
}

func showForgotPasswordAlert(){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Forgot password", message: "Please provide your valid email. Reset link will be sent to your email address", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler:nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

fileprivate func resetUIToInitialState(){
    isResettingPassword = false
    forgotPasswordButton.setTitle("Forgot password", for: UIControlState())
    passwordTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    passwordTextField.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    passwordTextField.isHidden = false
    loginButton.setTitle("Login", for: UIControlState())
    emailTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.next
    topInfoLabel.text = "Login to play"
}

fileprivate func login(){

    let email : String = emailTextField.text!
    let password : String = passwordTextField.text!

    if email != "" && password != "" {

        CommunicationManager.login(email, password: password,
                                   onSuccess: {json -> Void in

                                    let token = Token()
                                    token.token = json["token"].stringValue
                                    token.tokenExpirationDate = TokenManager.decodePayloadReturnExpirationTime(json["token"].stringValue)
                                    DataManager.token = token

                                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToUniversityController", sender: self)

        },onFailure: { error -> Void in
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "TRY AGAIN", message:
                "login failed", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler:nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })

    }else{
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Try again", message: "email & password are required", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler:nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

fileprivate func resetPassword(){

    let email : String = emailTextField.text!
    if email != "" {

        CommunicationManager.passwordRecovery(email,
                                              onSuccess: {json -> Void in
                                                self.showPasswordRecoverySuccess()
                                                self.resetUIToInitialState()
        },onFailure: { error -> Void in
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Try again", message: "please provide valid email", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler:nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
    }else{
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Try again", message: "email is required", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler:nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


fileprivate func showPasswordRecoverySuccess(){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Password recovery", message: "password recovery link is sent to your email", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler:nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func loadUI(){
    topInfoLabel.text = "Login to play"
    emailTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.next

    passwordTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done       
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(LoginController.keyboardWillShowNotification(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(LoginController.keyboardWillHideNotification(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    //self.view.endEditing(true)
    if textField == emailTextField{
        if isResettingPassword == false{
            passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }else{
            self.view.endEditing(true)
        }            
    }
    if textField == passwordTextField{
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    return true
}

//MARK Private functions
func keyboardWillShowNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("keyboardWillShow")

    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {

        if let keyboardHeight = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? AnyObject)?.cgRectValue.size.height {
            if keyboardIsShown == false {
                uiHolderViewCenterConstraint.constant = uiHolderCenterInitialValue! - keyboardHeight
                keyboardIsShown = true
            }

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillHideNotification(_ notification: Notification) {

    uiHolderViewCenterConstraint.constant = uiHolderCenterInitialValue!
    keyboardIsShown = false
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Simulator App on the Mac, the keyboard used by default is the Mac keyboard so it will not display it on the screen. To show it you have to go in the simulator to `Hardware > Keyboard > Toggle Software Keyboard` or `⌘K` for simplicity.

Comment: No, I am testing on my mobile! Thank you for the answer!